# Errors in moving from Eclipse (Indigo EE) to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, tomcat6

I'm sure it's something simple, but I have over 100 errors like:

[image]

and:

[image]

I pointed in the `Edit Configuration` to the right location of Tomcat, so what am I missing ?

## Edit:

O.k, thanks to @CrazyCoder I added `Tomcat` to the `Module Dependencies`, so now I have left with one module that I don't know where it should be: `JUnit`:

[image]

## Edit 2:

@CrazyCoder gave the answer: `%IDEA_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\junit-4.10.jar`

Comment: If you use Gradle for dependency management, then it's able to generate metadata files for Eclipse and IntelliJ which set the classpaths up correctly, so avoiding this sort of trouble. It's a huge boon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Tomcat application server to the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) with the **Provided** scope.

Comment: That threw many errors, I now have to add `JUnit`. Where it is located ?